# What is the best way to add a custom search form to the wordpress navigation menu?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a search form that is fetching some data from a database and then showing the data on a page on my website , I want to add this form to my Wordpress website , Not the wordpress search form , But the form I created .

What is the best way to include this search form and the PHP script ? Should I insert the html code directly to the header.php file that its action would be the PHP file that contains my script ? Or there is another better way?

I have the html code in an html file , and the PHP script , and Css file, What is the best way to include them to my wordpress website?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your header file but you would lose those changes when you updated your theme.

The correct thing to do is to [create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), copy the header.php file from the parent theme to the child theme and change it there. There are a few of plugins that you can use to create child themes.

You should also add your css file to the child theme and enqueue that in the functions.php file in your child theme.

When you make the child theme the websites theme, Wordpress will use all of the templates in the main theme except for the header.php file.

Smashing pumpkins has a [good tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/).